# Unrestricted Grammar: { sss | s exists in {a,b}* }

Tags: grammar, turing-complete

What would be a way to construct an unrestricted grammar for sss? I know that in order to construct ss, you need to construct ss^r and then re-reverse the second string, but how would that be done for sss?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few bugs in this but the idea should get you on the right track.

```
// section 1
S := LTR
T := ATWX | BTYZ | N

// section 2
WW' := W'W
WY' := Y'W
YW' := W'Y
YY' := Y'Y

// section 3
WX' := W'X'
WZ' := W'Z'
YX' := Y'X'
YZ' := Y'Z'

// section 4
XW' := W'X
XX' := X'X
XY' := Y'X
XZ' := Z'X
ZW' := W'Z
ZX' := X'Z
ZY' := Y'Z
ZZ' := Z'Z

// section 5
XR  := X'R
ZR  := Z'R

// section 6
NW' := W'N
NX' := X'N
NY' := Y'N
NZ' := Z'N
NR  := Q

// section 7
AQ  := Qa
W'Q := Qa
X'Q := Qa
BQ  := Qb
Y'Q := Qb
Z'Q := Qb
LQ  := e
```

Section 1 sets out the basic scheme. We're going to mark the beginning and end of our working space with L and R to be perfectly explicit. T is our working space and L and R are the left and right markers. Our working space can add either three `a`s (these are what A, W, and X will become later) or add three `b`s (these are what B, Y and Z will become later) or it can quit by generating the special nonterminal N. N is going to be what turns our string of nonterminals into a string of terminals, as we'll see later.

So we need `xxx` for `x` in `(a+b)*`. `A` and `B` get added to the end of the first `x` because of the way we set up the productions. The job of section 2 is to make sure that the `W` and `Y` get added to the end of the second `x`. Unfortunately, our productions put the `W` and `Y` at the beginning of the second `x` so, without correction, we'd end up with `xx^R`. Section 2 corrects this problem by "floating" the `W` and `Y` to the right as long as they are to the left of a `W` or `Y` that has already found its proper place. `W`s and `Y`s can't pass each other and so this guarantees they will end up in the proper sequence once the music stops.

Section 3 shows how the symbols in the second occurrence of `x` find their correct positions. Basically, they move to the right (based on section 2) until they find symbols of the third `x` that are in their proper places. Since the symbols of the second `x` have their proper place before the symbols of the third `x`, the last possible right before either symbol of the third `x` (`X` or `Z`) is the right position for every symbol of the second `x`. So we float right all the way to the end of the second `x`.

We repeat the process for the third `x` in section 4, although we have to let these symbols (`X` and `Z`) float past all the symbols from the second or third `x` that have already found their proper places. These symbols can't pass themselves and so by the same logic as we saw in section 2 we'll get the symbols in the correct sequence.

Section 5 says when to stop floating symbols that make up the third `x` to the right. Remember the end of working space marker `R`? The last symbol of the third `x` occurs all the way at the right, right before `R`. So that's when we know we have found the proper place for the symbol.

Section 6 begins the process of finishing off our derivation. We have a lovely string of nonterminals and we want to turn these into terminals. The first thing we do is float `N` to the right past the well-placed symbols of the second and third `x`s all the way to the end of string marker `R`. We don't need `R` for anything, so we transform `N` into `Q`. As we'll see in the next section `Q` is what makes the magic happen.

Section 7 outlines how `Q` floats left back through the entire string of nonterminals that have found their proper place all the way to `L`, changing the nonterminals to the proper terminal along the way. Once it finds `L`, it obliterates both nonterminals leaving only a string of terminal symbols in its wake. The derivation is complete.

To illustrate the process, let's generate `aabaabaab`.

```
S
-> LTR 
-> LATWXR 
-> LAATWXWXR 
-> LAABTYZWXWXR
-> LAABNYZWXWXR
-> LAABNYZWXWX'R
-> LAABNYZWXW'X'R
-> LAABNYZWW'XX'R
-> LAABNYZWW'X'XR
-> LAABNYZWW'X'X'R
-> LAABNYZW'WX'X'R
-> LAABNYZW'W'X'X'R
-> LAABNYW'ZW'X'X'R
-> LAABNYW'W'ZX'X'R
-> LAABNYW'W'X'ZX'R
-> LAABNYW'W'X'X'ZR
-> LAABNYW'W'X'X'Z'R
-> LAABNW'YW'X'X'Z'R
-> LAABNW'W'YX'X'Z'R
-> LAABNW'W'Y'X'X'Z'R
-> LAABW'NW'Y'X'X'Z'R
-> LAABW'W'NY'X'X'Z'R
-> LAABW'W'Y'NX'X'Z'R
-> LAABW'W'Y'X'NX'Z'R
-> LAABW'W'Y'X'X'NZ'R
-> LAABW'W'Y'X'X'Z'NR
-> LAABW'W'Y'X'X'Z'Q
-> LAABW'W'Y'X'X'Qb
-> LAABW'W'Y'X'Qab
-> LAABW'W'Y'Qaab
-> LAABW'W'Qbaab
-> LAABW'Qabaab
-> LAABQaabaab
-> LAAQbaabaab
-> LAQabaabaab
-> LQaabaabaab
-> aabaabaab
```